# Passing const reference or shared pointer / vector and assign to non-reference member

Tags: c++11, reference, constants, shared-ptr, stdvector

CPP check is complaining about this construction:

`void setThing(std::shared_ptr<Thing> theThing)
{
  memberThing = theThing;
}`

where memberThing is a `std::shared_ptr<Thing>`.

When changing to:
`void setThing(const std::shared_ptr<Thing>& theThing);`

cppcheck is not complaining anymore.

I need a shared pointer, I can't guarantee theThing will exist forever, so I don't want to have a member reference. But why is a const reference working when assigning it to a not-reference member? And what happens actually? Is the shared pointer copied to memberThing? Where did the reference go?

And actually exactly the same question for

`void setThings(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> theThings)
{
  memberThings = theThings;
}`

where memberThing is a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>>`.

When using this construction, what is happening with the vector? Is it copied? What happens when the original vector is destroyed? Can I better use the first version or the second?

I am quite confused a const vector& can be assigned to a vector (not-reference). Is that a good idea anyway? What is the best thing to do in this situation? And why?

Comment: 11 questions in one post. That's too many, IMO.

Comment: What do you mean by complaining?  What is the message?  A reference is essentially an alias so an assignment from a const reference to a non-reference type is no different from assigning one vector to another.  A const reference is typically used to avoid extra copies during the function call.  You should probably give a more complete example and specify the message that CPP Check is giving.

Comment: Both code fragments you show are valid C++. I don't know what `cppcheck` is, but to the extent it complains, it's likely about the points of style rather than substance.

Comment: The message is: Summary: Function parameter 'theThing' should be passed by reference.
Message: Parameter 'theThing' is passed by value. It could be passed as a (const) reference which is usually faster and recommended in C++.